# how to declare variable with special type in Typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm loading a json file and need the fields to have the same name

```
export interface People{

name: string
age: number
alive?: boolean
}
```

json comes like this

```
{
 {
 "name": "teste1"
 "age": 41
 "alive?": true
 }
}
```

load the json

```
@Injectable()
export class Peoples{
constructor(private http: Http){}

peoples(): Observable<People[]>{
    return this.http.get(`${DEEP_API}/people`)
    .map(response => response.json())
}
}
```

My problem is that the Person does not recognize the "?" in the "alive?"

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property name contains special characters you need to put it in `''`

```
export interface People{
    name: string
    age: number
    'alive?': boolean
}
```

**Note** `alive?: boolean` is valid syntax, but it means the property named `alive` is optional, not that the property is named `alive?`

To access the property you need to use `person['alive?']`

Comment: I tried to call it {{people.alive?}}, but it gave this error

"Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: {{People.alive?}}"

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Titan said, you should also be aware that by choosing to use a special character in the property name you will then be required to use **bracket notation** `["alive?"]` to access that properties value.